# Exceptions in LEX&YACC

Tags: parsing, exception, yacc, lex

I'm developing a lex/yacc c compiler.

In order to handle failures and parse errors, I want to deploy an exception system handler.

Actually only a "parse error" message is handled whatever the problem is.for example:

`typedef struct , struct_name{...}` this input will produce a parsing error because of the extra comma.

My purpose is to throw a contextual exception,giving us the possibility to focus exactly where the problem is.such as for this example :
*"Invalid structure declaration "*

I really need help to solve this problème.

Comment: I first thought that i should specify a set of error messages for each validated grammar and if any error is handled it will throw the exception corresponding to the current grammar.
I didn't know if it's feasible or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go into your parser. As it runs, it gets tokens from the lexer. If the next token does not "fit" the current rule, then you have a problem. Luckily, there already exists a section for dealing with these situations! See [bison error recovery](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Recovery.html#Error-Recovery) for the gnu version of yacc and how to deal with this. It'll go through the concepts, and variables to deal with just the situation you have here.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i can't really use flex/bison solution,only lex and yacc.Is there any similar solution for it?

Comment: @Aymanadou Bison is the GNU version of yacc. It should be *almost* identical. Same goes for flex. They are open source, extended versions of lex and yacc. Bison's error recovery section should still apply exactly to yacc code.